# Laravel deploy in sub-directory on a webserver

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, deployment, directory

I need some help with my httacces files. I uploaded an "erp" subfolder into my webserver which contains all of the files of my laravel app. When i try to open in my browser i got an 403 error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /erp/ on this server.
```

How can i solve this problem? I show you my .httacces file:

in the root:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !GOOGLE404probe
RewriteRule ^erp/(.*)$ public/$1 [L] -------> Here i try something but it looks like not working.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And i dont have htacces file in my erp folder.

My server is based on linux and i already moded the erp files to 755 permissions.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache or nginx user, with 755 folder permissions the files should be owned by that user, this also applies to your erp folder

The usual user / group in apache is www-data but it can be changed in the configuration

Comment: I tried to change permissions but i didnt work for me :(